# Django админка - inline к несвязанным объектам модели

Tags: django, foreign-key, inline, админка, many-to-many

Доброе время суток.
Необходимо добавить в админку django inline блок для вывода несвязанных с текущим объектом объектов другой модели

Имеются модели A, B, C. Модель B связана через FK с моделью А, и через M2M с моделью C. В админке для страницы редактирования объектов модели A нужно вывести inline с объектами модели C, несвязанными с моделью A

Инлайн полностью readonly, а все это необходимо, чтобы можно было создать связь для несвязанных объектов

Много чего перепробовал, пока безуспешно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, убив некоторое количество времени, написал свой ModelAdminInline, выпилив все, что связано с fk. 
Также пришлось заменить базовый формсет для инлайнов, так как в них тоже используются ключи. Новый формсет унаследовал от BaseModelFormSet, повзаимсвовав часть методов из инлайновского.

Спасибо всем, кто уделелил время хотя бы на просмотр вопроса.